# Javascript Multiple If.Else

Tags: javascript, if-statement

We have spent a lot of time using search engine optimization for our web site and in the event a mobile user is using one of the search engines, we are trying to redirect a mobile user to the mobile designed web pages that mirror the normal web pages which are set up in a subfolder /mobile/.

On the main non-mobile pages the variables are captured:

```
<% ThisPage = Request.ServerVariables("URL") %>
<% ThisVAR = "?" & Request.Querystring %>
```

These variables go to to an include file to check to see if the user is a mobile user or not, and if so, redirect to a page a mobile user might be searching for exists in mobile format for our site. If the user is on a mobile device and we do not have a mobile version of the page they are searching for, it should redirect to the mobile folder root.

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
if (screen.width <= 481)
{
    if (ThisPage = "/faqs.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/menu_faq.asp" }
    else {

    if (ThisPage = "/search.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/mobile_search.asp" }
else {

    if (ThisPage = "/mte_contacts.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/menu_contacts.asp" }
else {

    if (ThisPage = "/mte_history.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/menu_history.asp" }
    else {

    if (ThisPage = "/mte_locations.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/menu_locations.asp" }
else {

    if (ThisPage = "/mte_shipping.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/menu_shipping.asp" }
else {

    if (ThisPage = "/shop_discontinued.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/mobile_discontinued.asp" }
else {

    if (ThisPage = "/shop_category.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/mobile_category.asp" + ThisVAR }
else {

    if (ThisPage = "/shop_commodity.asp") { document.location = "../mobile/mobile_commodity.asp" + ThisVAR }

else { document.location = "../mobile/" }
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
}
</script>
```

I have been searching through solutions for a javascript if..else issue I am having and I cannot find anything that corrects my syntax error I have in my code.  I am getting the redirect to work, but it is not going to the correct mobile page and I cannot get the correct logic in place.  Any help would be appreciated.  Currently, testing on my mobile device to go to the /mnt_history.asp file but it redirects to /mobile/menu_faq.asp

Comment: You should be using a map anyway, and reduce it to a single line (plus the map declaration). You have a tiny number of exceptional cases. If nothing else, don't nest the ifs like that, use if/else if. Note that proper indentation would almost certainly fix your inability to find the error.

Comment: And if not using a map, use at least a switch statement.

Comment: I would recommend you design your site to use responsive design, then use the same pages for all browsers and devices. Obviously dis isn't answering your question though...

Comment: That's an interesting way to nest conditionals, but the core problem is that you use `=` instead of `==`. Not that the whole structure shouldn't be completely redesigned.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a bunch of if-elses, a lookup table is probably a better method.
It's more compact and easier to see all of the mappings in one place.

```
var mobileMapper = {
    "/faqs.asp"              : "../mobile/menu_faq.asp",
    "/search.asp"            : "../mobile/mobile_search.asp",
    "/mte_contacts.asp"      : "../mobile/menu_contacts.asp",
    "/mte_history.asp"       : "../mobile/menu_history.asp",
    "/mte_locations.asp"     : "../mobile/menu_locations.asp",
    "/mte_shipping.asp"      : "../mobile/menu_shipping.asp",
    "/shop_discontinued.asp" : "../mobile/mobile_discontinued.asp",
    "/shop_category.asp"     : "../mobile/mobile_category.asp" + ThisVAR ,
    "/shop_commodity.asp"    : "../mobile/mobile_commodity.asp" + ThisVAR 
};

if (screen.width <= 481) {
    document.location = mobilMapper[ThisPage] || "../mobile/";
}
```

Comment: OK, I applied the code above into the include file and made the small change to the name "mobilMapper[ThisPage]".  Now, when I try to go to the mte_history.asp file on the mobile device, I do not get any redirection, the met_history.asp page loads on the mobile device.  I thought it could be the "ThisPage" variable not passing properly, but when replacing the include file on the main page with the script above, the mobile device acts the same way....